# How to Wrap a Commad Line Executable In a .app Package?

Tags: user-interface, macos, opengl, glut

I wrote an OpenGL+GLUT game for Mac OS X that's currently launched through the command line. I'd like to make opening the game more user-friendly by putting it into a .app package, so regular users would be able to open the game like any other program. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

AppleScript or Platypus.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is to simply go and use XCode.

1. Create new project. (You can make it blank.)
2. Create a target, if necessary. Blank projects don't come with targets.
3. Minimally, add OpenGL.framework into the project. You may need to add Cocoa, Carbon and other frameworks, depending on what you used. If you used SDL or GLUT, add their frameworks as well.
4. Finally, add all source files into the project. Don't forget to add them into the target you created.

It's also customary to add all your resources to the project, so they get copied into the .app. Then, access the resources by `fopen()ing` from `your.app/Contents/Resources`.

If you have more specific questions, feel free to update your question or create a new one and I'll do what I can to help. (You can drop a comment to this answer if/when you update/create question.)